# Grafico com barra de erros em R

Tags: r, gráfico

Ola,

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico em linhas e barras de erros, mas os erros estão sendo plotados por cima da primeira linha, e não na segunda.... e minha legenda não esta sendo impressa. Vocẽ poderia ver o que esta errado?
Segue o código:

```
V_drone = c(.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0)
Tempo_Incremental_Antigo = c(2589.9, 1905.6, 1567, 1324.5, 1218.6,1119)
Tempo_Incremental_Novo = c(2455.5, 1678.5,1370.8,1147.6, 996.59,911);
Tempo_error_A = c(52.35233201, 87.73976673,88.0883395,49.61566573,192.8685591,50.74248713)
Tempo_error_N = c(46.04164781,56.39592184,75.66563876,64.87500803,161.2008043,75.55329245)

plot(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Antigo, ylab=expression("Overall Time(s)"),xlab=expression("Drone speed(m/s)"),col="blue", pch=15, ylim=c(0,3500), cex=1.3, type="b")
arrows(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Antigo, V_drone, Tempo + Tempo_error_A, length=0.1,angle = 90,col="blue")
arrows(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Antigo, V_drone, Tempo - Tempo_error_A, length=0.1,angle = 90,col="blue")

points(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Novo, ylab=expression("Overall Time(s)"), pch=15, ylim=c(0,3500), cex=1.3, type="b", col="red")
arrows(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Novo, V_drone, Tempo + Tempo_error_N, length=0.1,angle = 90, col="red")
arrows(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Novo, V_drone, Tempo - Tempo_error_N, length=0.1,angle = 90, col="red")

legend(20,30,legend=c("Fotossínte", "Condutância estomática"),pch=c(15,16),bty="n")
text(5,30,"Gráfico A")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema da linha de erro pelo que entendi foi pelo nome da variável do valor central, consertando ela as linhas são desenhadas.

A legenda o problema foram os valores de x e y fornecidos, você estava criando ela fora do valor do eixo x do gráfico. A mesma coisa para o texto.

E recomendo quando for postar algo com gráfico já postar ele junto que costuma facilitar as sugestões :)

```r
V_drone = c(.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0)
Tempo_Incremental_Antigo = c(2589.9, 1905.6, 1567, 1324.5, 1218.6,1119)
Tempo_Incremental_Novo = c(2455.5, 1678.5,1370.8,1147.6, 996.59,911);
Tempo_error_A = c(52.35233201, 87.73976673,88.0883395,49.61566573,192.8685591,50.74248713)
Tempo_error_N = c(46.04164781,56.39592184,75.66563876,64.87500803,161.2008043,75.55329245)

plot(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Antigo, ylab=expression("Overall Time(s)"),xlab=expression("Drone speed(m/s)"),col="blue", pch=15, ylim=c(0,3500), cex=1.3, type="b")
arrows(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Antigo, V_drone, Tempo_Incremental_Antigo + Tempo_error_A, length=0.1,angle = 90,col="blue")
arrows(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Antigo, V_drone, Tempo_Incremental_Antigo - Tempo_error_A, length=0.1,angle = 90,col="blue")

points(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Novo, ylab=expression("Overall Time(s)"), pch=15, ylim=c(0,3500), cex=1.3, type="b", col="red")
arrows(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Novo, V_drone, Tempo_Incremental_Novo + Tempo_error_N, length=0.1,angle = 90, col="red")
arrows(V_drone,Tempo_Incremental_Novo, V_drone, Tempo_Incremental_Novo - Tempo_error_N, length=0.1,angle = 90, col="red")

legend(2,3000,legend=c("Fotossínte", "Condutância estomática"), pch=c(15,16), col = c("blue", "red"), bty="n")
text(1.75, 3400,"Gráfico A")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>